# Can't buy a suit in Meltdown because the store is always closed

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In the start of this mission when you have to buy a suit, the store is never open at any time of the day and Jimmy never shows up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My suggestion would be to save your game and restart your box, this sounds like a bug.  I've also seen issues where the game thinks I'm in a mission already (especially regarding the cult missions...) so I had to kill myself and wake up at the hospital to "fail" the mission and get free again.

Comment: Tried that part of the day yesterday with no luck. :(

Comment: There may be other stores.

Answer (score -1):

Just open the door while standing outside and shoot the woman in the counter, do this 3 times or so and u can skip the piece!